# Python - How to pass Structures of array to function on shared file

Tags: python, arrays, cuda, shared-libraries

I have researched for hours,

1. [How to access data from pointer in struct from Python with ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912065/how-to-access-data-from-pointer-in-struct-from-python-with-ctypes)
2. [Using Python Ctypes to pass struct pointer to a DLL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867670/using-python-ctypes-to-pass-struct-pointer-to-a-dll-function)
3. [Convert C array of pointers to Python array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069736/convert-c-array-of-pointers-to-python-array-of-structures)
4. etc,

but I have not resolved my problem.

File: test.cu

```
        extern TEST_API int fft_coba1d(cplx in, cplx outfft, cplx outdft, cplx outfftc, unsigned int size) // int argc, char **argv
    {
    ....
        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &in.x, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &in.y, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outfft.x, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outfft.y, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outdft.x, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outdft.y, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outfftc.x, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaHostAlloc((void**) &outfftc.y, nBytes, cudaHostAllocDefault));

    ....

        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outfft.x));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outfft.y));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outfftc.x));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outfftc.y));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outdft.x));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(outdft.y));
}
```

File: test.h

```
#define DLL_FILE
#define EXPORT_FUNC
#ifdef DLL_FILE
#ifdef EXPORT_FUNC
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define TEST_API extern
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


typedef struct  
{
    float* x;
    float* y;
}cplx;      
....
extern TEST_API int fft_coba1d(cplx in, cplx outfft, cplx outdft, cplx outfftc, unsigned int size);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

File: test.py

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class cplx(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", POINTER(c_float)),
                ("y", POINTER(c_float))]

def get_cuda_fft():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('fftcoba.dll')#, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
    func = dll.fft_coba1d
    func.argtypes = [cplx, cplx,  cplx, cplx, c_uint]
    func.restype = c_int
    return func

__cuda_fft = get_cuda_fft()

def cuda_fft(a, b, c, d, size):
    __cuda_fft(a, b, c, d, size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size=8
    size = int(size)
    print size

    in_ = cplx()
    outfft = cplx()
    outdft = cplx()
    outfftc = cplx()
    in_.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))
    in_.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))

    outfft.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))
    outfft.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))

    outdft.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))
    outdft.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))

    outfftc.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))
    outfftc.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size, dtype=float))

    cuda_fft(in_, outfft, outdft, outfftc , size)

    print in_[:4]
```

I get this error,
[Python Stopped Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MsIr.png)

How to Pass Structure of array on function that linked to shared library (dll file)?

How to get result from function on shared library?

Comment: CUDA is not C. Just because something has the letter "C" in its name, that does not mean it is related to the C language. And IIRC, CUDA source code uses `.cu` extension.

Comment: I had edit it my question. I am using test.cu instead of test.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem,

File Test.py

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time


class cplx(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.POINTER(c_float)),
                ("y", ctypes.POINTER(c_float))]              

# extract cuda_sum function pointer in the shared object cuda_sum.so
#
def get_cuda_fft():
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('fftcoba.dll')#, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)


    func = dll.fft_coba1d

    func.argtypes = [cplx, cplx, cplx, cplx, cplx ,c_int]                    
    func.restype = None
    return func

# create __cuda_sum function with get_cuda_sum()
__cuda_fft = get_cuda_fft()

# convenient python wrapper for __cuda_sum
# it does all job with types convertation
# from python ones to C++ ones 
def cuda_fft(in_, offt, odft, offtc, ocufft, size):
    __cuda_fft(in_, offt, odft, offtc, ocufft, size)

# testing, sum of two arrays of ones and output head part of resulting array
if __name__ == '__main__':
    size=sys.argv[1]
    size = int(size)

    p = 1
    while (size>p):
        p *= 2

    if size != p:
        size = p

    s1=time.clock()
    IN = cplx()
    outDFT = cplx()
    outFFT = cplx()
    outFFTC = cplx()
    outCUFFT = cplx()



    IN.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    IN.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outDFT.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outDFT.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outFFT.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outFFT.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outFFTC.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outFFTC.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outCUFFT.x = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))
    outCUFFT.y = (c_float * size)(np.array(size,dtype=c_float))


    # print type(Inputx)
    # print Inputx.shape
    i = np.linspace(0,size-1, size)
    f1 = time.clock()
    print 'Exection Time for initializing Data : ', f1-s1, 'Second'

    s2 = time.clock()
    # size = ctypes.sc_uint(size)
    cuda_fft(IN, outFFT, outDFT, outFFTC, outCUFFT, size)
    f2 = time.clock()
    print 'Execution Time for Cuda FFT : ', f2-s2, ' Seconds'

    print 'From Output FFT Method ?'
    print outFFT.x[3]


    s3 = time.clock()
 # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////METHOD COPY DATA C_FLOAT POINTER TO NP>FLOAT//////////////////////////////////////////////    
    Inputx = npct.as_array(IN.x, shape=(size,))
    Inputy = npct.as_array(IN.y, shape=(size,))
    outfftx = npct.as_array(outFFT.x, shape=(size,))
    outdftx = npct.as_array(outDFT.x, shape=(size,))
    outfftcx = npct.as_array(outFFTC.x, shape=(size,))
    outcufftx = npct.as_array(outCUFFT.x, shape=(size,))

    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////METHOD COPY DATA C_FLOAT POINTER TO NP>FLOAT//////////////////////////////////////////////

    for i in range(size):
        Inputx[i] = IN.x[i]
        Inputy[i] = IN.y[i]
        outfftx[i] = outFFT.x[i]
        outdftx[i] = outDFT.x[i]
        outfftcx[i] = outFFTC.x[i]
        outcufftx[i] = outCUFFT.x[i]

    i = np.linspace(0,size-1, size)
    print type(Inputx)
    # print Inputx.shape[0]
    print i.shape
    f3 = time.clock()
    print 'Execution Time for Copying Data to array Python is ', f3-s3, 'Seconds'

    plt.subplot(511)
    plt.plot(i,Inputx)
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.title("Input",color='r')

    plt.subplot(512)
    plt.plot(i,outfftx)
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.title("FFT CPU",color='r')

    plt.subplot(513)
    plt.plot(i,outdftx)
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.title("DFT CPU",color='r')

    plt.subplot(514)
    plt.plot(i,outfftcx)
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.title("FFT CUDA",color='r')

    plt.subplot(515)
    plt.plot(i,outcufftx)
    plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
    plt.title("CUFFT CUDA",color='r')

    plt.show()

    del Inputy
    del outfftx
    del outdftx
    del outfftcx
    del outcufftx
```

file test.h

```
typedef struct  
{
    float* x;
    float* y;
}cplx;     

extern RIZ_API void fft_coba1d(cplx in, 
                            cplx outfft,  
                            cplx outdft, 
                            cplx outfftc, 
                            cplx ocufft, 
                                 int size); // int argc, char **argv
```